# R: How to make out of a specific column of NYC zip codes a new column with the right boroughs?

Tags: r, statistics, nyc, brooklyn

This is my first Question and I couldn't find a answer on the web..

I want to make a statistic of the absolute number of cases in the 5 boroughs of NYC.

**PROBLEM:**

I have a column in a data frame in R, which is untidy. It  should contain only the boroughs of NYC for each case. But it is mixed of 250+ cases which are one of the 3 below:

1. Zip Codes which are either Bronx, Brooklyn, Manhattan, Queens or Staten Island.
2. abbreviations like 'bx-12345' for Bronx, 'qu-23452' for Queens, 'ma-23412' for manhattan(...) and
3. half of the cases is really 'Bronx', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan' (...). No need to change it.

**QUESTION:** How to match it with the Borough?

I have a list of the Zip Codes of each Borough.

1. How can I exchange the Zip codes with the matching borough?
2. How can I take the first 2 letters of a string like `'BX'` in `'BX-12345'` to match it for all Boroughs?

Examples from the df:

[1] "BK-14"     "QN-12"     "BX-12"     "SI-01"     "BX-03"     "11216"     "SI-01"     "BX-05"     "11249"     "42"
 [11] "10009"     "QN-05"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10457"
 [21] "10458"     "BX-04"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10453"     "10467"     "QN-07"     "10029"     "10028"
 [31] "11221"     "10452"     "11206"     "Manhattan" "Manhattan" "36"        "11212"     "Manhattan" "10032"     "10459"
 [41] "10459"     "10459"     "10459"     "BK-12"     "BK-15"     "BX-12"     "10467"     "10029"     "SI-01"     "36"
 [51] "11232"     "11206"     "10002"     "10455"     "10455"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"
 [61] "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "SI-03"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"
 [71] "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "11239"     "10459"     "10455"     "10468"     "11216"
 [81] "11249"     "10460"     "Brooklyn"  "11206"     "11238"     "10459"     "11206"     "11206"     "10468"     "10468"
 [91] "10002"     "10456"     "SI-01"     "QN-08"     "BX-09"     "10022"     "11691"     "Manhattan" "Manhattan" "BX-07"

Answer (score 0):

Consider a data.frame with untidy boroughs:

```r
df <- data.frame(borough = c("12345", "BX-12345", "Bronx"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#>    borough
#> 1    12345
#> 2 BX-12345
#> 3    Bronx
```

And a mapping table:

```r
map <- data.frame(zip = "12345", abbr = "BX", name = "Bronx", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
map
#>     zip abbr  name
#> 1 12345   BX Bronx
```

First reduce "abbr-zip" to "abbr":

```r
df$borough <- gsub("^([^-]*)-.*$", "\\1", df$borough)
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN with mapping table on `zip`, taking in all matching values:

```r
df1 <- merge(df, map, by.x = "borough", by.y = "zip", all.x = TRUE)
df$borough <- ifelse(is.na(df1$name), df1$borough, df1$name)
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN with mapping table on `abbr`, taking in all matching values:

```r
df2 <- merge(df, map, by.x = "borough", by.y = "abbr", all.x = TRUE)
df$borough <- ifelse(is.na(df2$name), df2$borough, df2$name)
```

Result:

```r
df
#>   borough
#> 1   Bronx
#> 2   Bronx
#> 3   Bronx
```

Actually it is simpler to map "abbr-zip" to "zip" with

```r
df$borough <- gsub("^[^-]*-(.*)*$", "\\1", df$borough)
```

After that the first LEFT OUTER JOIN is sufficient. And you do not need `abbr` in the mapping table.